# About how to monitor ephemeral storage usage on AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

From Apr 30, 2021, Amazon ECS on AWS Fargate allows you to configure the size of ephemeral storage for Tasks. However, I am consider about ways so that I monitor the usage of ephemeral storage . Is there anyway?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I did not find any other solution for Fargate. Therefore, I created a sidecar container that use amazon/cloudwatch-agent docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/cloudwatch-agent) to get the information about disk usage and then put custom metrics to CloudWatch.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to enable [Container Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/ContainerInsights.html) in order to monitor the ephemeral storage used in each container. Once enabling that, you will have many more metrics in CloudWatch related to your ECS Cluster, Services, Tasks, and Contianers.

Note that enabling Container Insights does increase your CloudWatch costs because these are considered custom metrics in CloudWatch.

Comment: Container insights do not track how much ephemeral storage is being used on ECS Fargate, (see the all the metrics [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Container-Insights-metrics-ECS.html))

It only tracks write/read bytes to the storage.